# Azure devOps 2020 RTW - Cannot login to Azure CLI - Using PAT

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-server-2020

I am trying to access Azure DevOps server 2020 using the Azure CLI using the following
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops-2020&tabs=windows)
The Token has full permission and i can access the server using the web portal from the same workstation.

RestAPI  Calls to same server works from this workstation

Getting the following error

```
Creating connection with personal access token.
Failed to authenticate using the supplied token.
Command ran in 28.202 seconds (init: 0.286, invoke: 27.916)
Suppress exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-2g1ftftt\azure\cli\__main__.py", line 60, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-2g1ftftt\azure\cli\__main__.py", line 53, in <module>
SystemExit: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-_1bqfhco\azure\cli\core\_profile.py", line 502, in get_current_account_user
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-_1bqfhco\azure\cli\core\_profile.py", line 511, in get_subscription
knack.util.CLIError: Please run 'az login' to setup account.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-_1bqfhco\azure\cli\core\decorators.py", line 74, in _wrapped_func
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-_1bqfhco\azure\cli\core\decorators.py", line 57, in _decorator
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-_1bqfhco\azure\cli\core\telemetry.py", line 522, in _get_user_azure_id
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-_1bqfhco\azure\cli\core\_profile.py", line 504, in get_current_account_user
knack.util.CLIError: There are no active accounts.

Suppress exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-2g1ftftt\azure\cli\__main__.py", line 60, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-2g1ftftt\azure\cli\__main__.py", line 53, in <module>
SystemExit: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-_1bqfhco\azure\cli\core\decorators.py", line 74, in _wrapped_func
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-_1bqfhco\azure\cli\core\telemetry.py", line 532, in _get_azure_subscription_id
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-_1bqfhco\azure\cli\core\_profile.py", line 528, in get_subscription_id
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-_1bqfhco\azure\cli\core\_profile.py", line 511, in get_subscription
knack.util.CLIError: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please try to use the `All accessible organizations` scope PAT and check if it could make changes? If it still doesn't work, could you please share  the  Specific version of Azure Devops server and the connect URL sample ?

Comment: tried "All accessible organizations scope PAT" same error Version 2020 RTW  Dev18.M170.6

Comment: Connect URL - https://aztest/MCollection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution was

1. Install The Beta Version of the Azure-Cli - https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindowsbeta
2. Set The following REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE - PEM [format](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html)

Comment: some more info and help from microsoft - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1264971/cannot-login-to-azure-cli-using-pat-ado-2020-rtw.html